# Compact collapsing of equations and paragraphs

Tags: spacing, equations, amsmath, align

I want to duplicate the compact look of G. K. Batchelor's fluid dynamics book. Where a paragraph terminates such that the mathematical expression can collapse up into the vertical space of the paragraph, the expression moves up. [If that makes no sense, see it on Google Books.](http://books.google.com/books?id=Rla7OihRvUgC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA386#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Can the `align` environment do this automatically? Or do I need to use another environment? I'm not aware of any way to do this automatically.

Comment: You might be after manipulating the value `\abovedisplayshortskip`. See [abovedisplayskip vs abovedisplayshortskip](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30909/abovedisplayskip-vs-abovedisplayshortskip).

Comment: don't know of any environment that produces that compact spacing automatically.  the `amsmath` `align` environment certainly doesn't, and if using left-hand equation numbers, it would be extremely difficult to implement.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a LaTeX approach at duplicating the typesetting in your link, as well as using @morbusg's `\abovedisplayshortskip` of `-.5\baselineskip` (plus some glue):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.05in]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\newcommand{\pfrac}[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}% Partial derivative
\begin{document}
\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{-.5\baselineskip plus 3pt}% Original value: 0pt plus 3pt
\noindent \textit{Local variation of the velocity magnitude}

Some simple but useful results follow immediately from the expression 
for local vorticity in terms of rectuangular co-ordinates with axes parallel 
to the location directions of~$\mathbf{u}$, of the principal normal to the streamline 
(directed towards the centre of curvature), and of the binomial to the 
streamline. If $(s,n,b)$ represent co-ordinates in these three dimensions 
respectively, and $(u,v,w)$ are the corresponding velocity components, we 
have
\[
  v=w=0, \quad 
  u=q, \quad 
  \pfrac{v}{s}=\frac{q}{R}, \quad 
  \pfrac{w}{s}=0
\]
locally, where~$R$ is the local radius of curvature of the streamline. The 
components of the vorticity locally are then
\[
  \omega_s=\pfrac{w}{n}-\pfrac{v}{b}, \quad 
  \omega_n=\pfrac{u}{b}, \quad 
  \omega_b=\frac{u}{R}-\pfrac{u}{n}.
\]
\leavevmode\rlap{Moreover,}%\hfill
\centerline{$\displaystyle
  \left(\pfrac{}{s},\pfrac{}{n},\pfrac{}{b}\right)u=
  \left(\pfrac{}{s},\pfrac{}{n},\pfrac{}{b}\right)q$}
%\hfill\null\\
locally. Hence, in irrotational flow we have
\begin{align}
  \pfrac{q}{n}=\frac{q}{R}, \quad \pfrac{q}{b}=0. \tag{6.2.13}\label{irrotational_flow}
\end{align}

The first of the relations~\eqref{irrotational_flow} shows that, when the streamlines \ldots

\end{document}
```

[`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) was used to reduce the margins and mimic the linked output.

The only difference in the output was from typesetting the line that has a centered alignment with respect to the text block, while still having text left-aligned ("Moreover," in this case). Some "trickery" (via `\rlap`) was used to obtain this, but that could also have been what the author did in their markup. As @egreg mentioned in comment, the use of `\leavevmode` is necessary if the paragraph was preceded by a blank line. As such, and for completeness (since it does no harm here...), I've added `\leavevmode`.

---

From a pedagogical point of view, the use of `\abovedisplayshortskip` is taken from the width of the (single) last line in the preceding paragraph. As such, it would take more than just modifying `\abovedisplayshortskip` to accommodate the display presented in your link for a general use-case when the previous paragraph consists of a single line, unless you're willing to do some compacting yourself using manual intervention (as I did in my example).

Comment: The `\rlap` works because after a displayed equation TeX resumes horizontal mode. Were `\rlap{Moreover,}\centerline{...}` after a blank line it wouldn't have worked, as neither `\rlap` nor `\centerline` start horizontal mode. So `\leavevmode\rlap` would be more appropriate, for the general case. Nice answer, anyway.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks; I see what you mean. I added that to my discussion.

Comment: Actually `\noindent` there does nothing, and if the line is at the start of a paragraph it mustn't be used. So ... ;-)

Answer (score 6):

Here's an excerpt from the linked document with Werner's suggested `\abovedisplayshortskip` set to negative half of `\baselineskip` (in plain-tex):

```
\abovedisplayshortskip=-.5\baselineskip
\def\p#1#2{{\partial#1\over\partial#2}}
\noindent\dots represent co-ordinates in these three directions
respectively, and $(u, v, w)$ are the corresponding velocity components,
we have
$$ v=w=0,\quad u=q,\quad\p vs={q\over R},\quad\p ws=0 $$
locally, where $R$ is the local radius of curvature of the streamline.
The components of the vorticity locally are then
$$ \omega_s=\p wn-\p vb,\quad\omega_n=\p ub,\quad\omega_b={u\over R}-\p un. $$
Moreover,
$$ \left(\p{}s,\p{}n,\p{}b\right)u=\left(\p{}s,\p{}n,\p{}b\right)q $$
locally. Hence, in irrotational flow we have
$$ \p qn={q\over R},\quad\p qb=0. \eqno(\oldstyle 6.2.13) $$

The first of the relations \dots
\bye
```

It looks like:
[image: negative abovedisplayshortskip]

Note that I didn't touch `abovedisplayskip`, only the `short` variant.

Comment: That Plain Tex did not use `\[..\]` or `\(..\)` or `\documentclass{..}` and those things that LaTeX does. I can delete the comment, so it does not confuse anyone.

Comment: @morbusg If you hover your mouse over your comment, you'll see a small "⨯" next to the time of posting.