# how to change spacing between align environments and equation environments?

Tags: spacing, equations, environments

I am using align and environment for various equations.

There is some space that comes before and after the equations that I would like to minimize.

Is there a single command that could be used to do that for all environment occurrences?

(I think some of it is automatically determined by Latex, but maybe I can give a maximal amount of space allowed?)

Comment: You could use `\vspace{<negative dimension>}` between the two.

Comment: The vertical space above and below the amsmath display-math environments is governed by the parameters `\abovedisplayskip` and, you guessed it, `\belowdisplayskip`. See the posting [abovedisplayskip vs abovedisplayshortskip](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30909/5001) for a longer discussion of these parameters and how they might be modified.

Answer (score 4):

although it's not possible to be sure what is really meant, without a compilable example, this sounds like the `align` and `equation` environments are set without any text between, like this:

```
\begin{align}
   ... \\
   ...
\end{align}
\begin{equation}
   ...
\end{equation}
```

this isn't recommended.  instead, it's possible to nest an `align` group within `gather`:

```
\begin{gather}
\begin{align}
   ... \\
   ...
\end{align}\\[6pt]
   ... \\
   ...
\end{gather}
```

the `[6pt]` is optional; it assumes that some additional space is wanted between the aligned material and the non-aligned equations.  (this optional directive can be used at any line break to increase or decrease the space between lines.)

all lines will be numbered, unless `\notag` is used on individual lines, or `aligned` is used to omit the number from that entire group.