# Reason of existense of the extra space in align environment and removal of it between two align environments

Tags: vertical-alignment, align

This is a follow-up question regarding the extra vertical space in amsmath's `align` environment. Why when in use `align` uses so much vertical space in contrast with other environments like for example `tabular` or `itemize`?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=0.3in, bottom=1.2in, left=0.8in, right=0.8in]{geometry}


\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setlength{\mathindent}{0cm}
\newcommand{\3}{\vspace{0.3cm}}

\title{}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

70

\begin{align*}
&e^{jz}=\cos z+j\sin z\\
&\cos z=(1/2)(2\cos z)=\\
&=(1/2)(2\cos z+j\sin z-j\sin z)=\\
&=(1/2)(\cos z+j\sin z+\cos z-j\sin z)=\\
&=(1/2)(e^{jz}+e^{-jz})
\end{align*}

80

\begin{itemize}
\item Item 1

\item Item 2

\end{itemize}

90

\begin{tabular}{c|c}
 Entry 1& Entry 2  \\
 Entry 3& Entry 4
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Also another image of the huge space between two `align` environments. Even without the blank lines the space is a lot.

[image]

```
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols*}{2}


\begin{align*}
&\text{70}\\
&e^{jz}=\cos z+j\sin z\\
&\cos z=(1/2)(2\cos z)=\\
&=(1/2)(2\cos z+j\sin z-j\sin z)=\\
&=(1/2)(\cos z+j\sin z+\cos z-j\sin z)=\\
&=(1/2)(e^{jz}+e^{-jz})
\end{align*}



\begin{align*}
&\text{207}\\
&x(t)=A_{c}\cos \theta(t)\\
&\theta(t)=2\pi f_{c}t+\phi(t)\\
&\phi(t)=K_{p}m(t)\\
&x(t)=A_{c}\cos[2\pi f_{c}t+K_{p}m(t)]
\end{align*}
```

Edit I:

As I mention in a comment I have tried the following code and there is no difference between two `align` environments, only between text and an `align` environment. Why doesn't work in the case of the two environments and how can I fix it so to work? Also what is the reason that this space exists?

```
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}
```

Comment: There is no extra space if you don't leave a blank line after `70`, which is wrong, because an alignment should never start a paragraph.

Comment: `tabular` is a simple table, different from the float `table`. You `tabular` is just below the line `90` since you left a blank line it was inserted just after, like a new paragraph.

Comment: @egreg even if there is no blank line there is still a lot of vertical space. I used the blank line here so to empasize what I meant.

Comment: @Sigur it is logical about the `tabular` but not for the other environments. I used `tabular` as a comparison because I think is the right output.

Comment: You should do tests with a full page since some vertical spaces are stretchable. Use the `lipsum` package and `\lipsum[1]` to produce dummy texts.

Comment: @Adam I can't see this “lot of space”.

Comment: @egreg look the vertical space of align in contrast with tabular or itemize.

Comment: @Adam, you should use blank line before `align` since it is a display environment and automatically insert vertical spaces above and below it. So you don't need the paragraph (which makes the space above bigger).

Comment: @Sigur I aggree and in my code I don't use blank line between the text and the align (as I said I used it here to empasize) but even with it there is a big difference if you compare it to the other environments.

Comment: Ops, sorry. I was saying *shouldn't use*.

Comment: The vertical space before mathematical environments is governed by the `abovedisplayskip` length that you can modify if needed: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30909/abovedisplayskip-vs-abovedisplayshortskip

Comment: @pluton I have tried it and there is no difference between two `align` environments, only between text and an `align` environment.

Comment: @Adam A blank line before a display environment is wrong; two consecutive display environments are wronger.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the documentation for the 'amsmath' package says that there should be no blank lines between consecutive displays.  instead, "subsidiary" environments should be used within another more inclusive environment.

for example:

```
text
\begin{gather*}
 \begin{aligned}
  a &= b + c\\
    &= d + e
 \end{aligned}\\
 \begin{aligned}
  fgh &= ijk + lmn\\
      &= opq
 \end{aligned}
\end{gather*}
```

please read the manual (`texdoc amsmath`) -- it's quite short,
and has useful examples.

Comment: Thank you I have read it but I missed that. So the space was a wrong behaviour because I didn't use `gather`? Also sorry but is there a way to break the equations in a new page or in a new column? Because with that way it creates a badbox if I write a lot of equations one under the other.

Comment: check the documentation for `\allowbreak` and `\allowdisplaybreaks`.  (i'm away from home, and unable to get access to my usual resources, so i'm answering from memory, which sometimes goes fuzzy.)

Comment: I have a question regarding your answer though. In my code the `align` environments are not consecutive as there is text between them. If I was writting a bigger documents with a lot of text in which I would like an `align` then the text and an `align` again what would happen then?

Comment: @Adam -- only if your alignments are consecutive do they need to be kept within the same display structure.  if text following an `align` starts a new paragraph, end the display environment and leave a blank line.  if it does *not* start a new paragraph, still end the display environment, but start the text without leaving a blank line.  only if two *different* display environments directly follow one another do they need to be "grouped" within a more comprehensive environment such as `gather`.

Comment: Ok i will try some cases.