# How to get rid of space between section and equation

Tags: spacing, sectioning, equations

I'm making a cheatsheet and need to get rid of as much unneeded space as possible. However, I just can't figure out how to get rid of this space that is added between a (sub)section title and an equation:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[8pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[paper=a5paper]{geometry}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\lineskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}

% Display mode equation spacing
\expandafter\def\expandafter\normalsize\expandafter{%
    \normalsize
    \setlength\abovedisplayskip{0pt}
    \setlength\belowdisplayskip{0pt}
    \setlength\abovedisplayshortskip{0pt}
    \setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{0pt}
}

\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\begin{equation*}
q = q_0 + q_1i + q_2j + q_3k = (q_0,q_1,q_2,q_3)
\end{equation*}
\section{Section}
Some text
\begin{equation*}
q = q_0 + q_1i + q_2j + q_3k = (q_0,q_1,q_2,q_3)
\end{equation*}
More text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It's not at all recommended to start a paragraph with a math display.

Comment: Thanks! As I said, I'm creating a cheat sheet, so many sections contain nothing but equations. I guess I could redefine the section command to work around my problem but I would like a more elegant solution.

Comment: Do you really need `\section`, then?

Comment: Not necessarily, but I would like to keep the conveniences of `\section`, such as being able to configure the spacing using titlespacing. Of course this could also be done with a custom command, but that seems like a complicated solution.

Comment: Also seems like you used both ways from here : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/410946/changing-vertical-spacing-before-and-after-math-display-mode/410948#410948... but one of them would be enough I suppose. In my answer I just used your code's "\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}" without really needed that

Comment: @koleygr Actually they don't seem to have exactly the same effect - but you're right, `\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}` is unneeded when I'm also redefining the displayskips.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `\noindent` before `\begin{equation}`:

```
\section{Section}
\noindent\begin{equation*}
q = q_0 + q_1i + q_2j + q_3k = (q_0,q_1,q_2,q_3)
\end{equation*}
```

The reason: TeX operates in vertical mode after `\section`. If display math starts in vertical mode, the horizontal mode is opened immediately and the line with `\parindent` is preceded. But you can avoid this line when there is no `\parindent`. This can be done by `\noindent`.

You can insert `\noindent` before each `\begin{equation}`: if the horizontal mode is opened already the `\noindent` does nothing. You can create your macro which generates `\noindent\begin{equation}` or re-define `\begin{equation}`.

Comment: Thanks, that works! But I don't really understand why - I already have `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}`, wouldn't that normally make `\noindent` unneeded?

Comment: @danmou A box with `\parindent` width is inserted when horizontal mode started. No matter that `\parindent=0pt`. The box with zero width is inserted in such case. There is only one situation when this `\parindent` box is not inserted: when the horizontal mode begins with `\noindent`. Finally: if `\parindent` box is inserted and display math is immediately followed then empty line is inserted before such display math.

Answer (score 4):

For a cheatsheet, I believe it's better to redefine `\section` and `\subsection`.

```
\documentclass[8pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[paper=a5paper]{geometry}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\renewcommand{\section}[1]{%
  \par
  \stepcounter{section}%
  \everypar{\textbf{\thesection\ #1}\quad\everypar{}}%
}
\renewcommand{\subsection}[1]{%
  \par
  \stepcounter{subsection}%
  \everypar{\textbf{\thesubsection\ #1}\quad\everypar{}}%
}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\lineskip}{0pt}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \setlength\abovedisplayskip{0pt}%
  \setlength\belowdisplayskip{0pt}%
  \setlength\abovedisplayshortskip{0pt}%
  \setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{0pt}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}
\begin{equation*}
q = q_0 + q_1i + q_2j + q_3k = (q_0,q_1,q_2,q_3)
\end{equation*}

\section{Section}
Some text for explaining the following equation
\begin{equation*}
q = q_0 + q_1i + q_2j + q_3k = (q_0,q_1,q_2,q_3)
\end{equation*}
More text follows the equation

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But `\makeatletter` shouldn't be needed right? I like the way you use `\AtBeginDocument` instead of the hack I was using (I got it from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69662/how-to-globally-change-the-spacing-around-equations), you might want to add your solution there).

Comment: @danmou I forgot to remove it, thanks for noting.

Answer (score 2):

Two ways to solve your problem:

```
\documentclass[8pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[paper=a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage{parskip}
%\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}


\def\mycommand{\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}%
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}%
\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}%
\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}}

\AtBeginDocument{\mycommand}

\let\oldnormalsize\selectfont
\def\selectfont{\oldnormalsize\mycommand}

\newenvironment{myeq}{\vspace{-10pt}\par\begin{equation*}}{\end{equation*}\vspace{-10pt}}

\newsavebox{\mybox}
\newlength{\mylength}
\def\myinleq#1{\savebox\mybox{$#1$}\settowidth{\mylength}{\usebox{\mybox}}\hspace{0.5\dimexpr\linewidth-\mylength-2\parindent\relax\relax}$#1$}

\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\begin{myeq}
q = q_0 + q_1i + q_2j + q_3k = (q_0,q_1,q_2,q_3)
\end{myeq}

\begin{myeq}
q_2 = q_0 + q_1i + q_2j + q_3k = (q_0,q_1,q_2,q_3)
\end{myeq}%emptyline needed here

\myinleq{q_3 = q_0 + q_1i + q_2j + q_3k = (q_0,q_1,q_2,q_3)}

\section{Section}
\noindent Some text
\begin{equation*}
q = q_0 + q_1i + q_2j + q_3k = (q_0,q_1,q_2,q_3)
\end{equation*}
More text
\end{document}
```

[image]