# How insert a piece of code before and after environment?

Tags: spacing, environments

An example, how decrease vertical space using `itemize`?

1. I can insert the code: `\addtolength{\itemsep}{-0.5em}` at begin each itemize.
2. I can define and use a new environment as:

   ```
   \newenvironment{myItemize}{
      \begin{itemize}
      \addtolength{\itemsep}{-0.5em}
      }{
      \end{itemize}
      }
   ```

   But how can I call `myItemize` without replace all `itemize`?

I want do the same thing for equations inserting `\vspace{-0.5em}` beginning and ending `equation` environment.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You should take a look at the `enumitem` package to define customised lists.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of ways to achieve this. First, by redefining the way `itemize` works. For this, let's see what the `itemize` environment looks like (from the LaTeX kernel, [`latex.ltx`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latex.ltx?view=co)):

```
\def\itemize{%
  \ifnum \@itemdepth >\thr@@\@toodeep\else
    \advance\@itemdepth\@ne
    \edef\@itemitem{labelitem\romannumeral\the\@itemdepth}%
    \expandafter
    \list
      \csname\@itemitem\endcsname
      {\def\makelabel##1{\hss\llap{##1}}}%
  \fi}
\let\enditemize =\endlist
```

Note that

```
\begin{itemize}
  <your list of items>
\end{itemize}
```

is roughly translated to

```
\begingroup
  \itemize
    <your list of items>
  \enditemize
\endgroup
```

So, one could just copy the definition of `\itemize` into your preamble and change it to suit your needs. Here's an example illustrating the changes mid-document:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item First
  \item Second
  \item Third
  \item Last
\end{itemize}

% Redefine \itemize (\def will overwrite the definition)
\makeatletter
\def\itemize{%
  \ifnum \@itemdepth >\thr@@\@toodeep\else
    \advance\@itemdepth\@ne
    \edef\@itemitem{labelitem\romannumeral\the\@itemdepth}%
    \expandafter
    \list
      \csname\@itemitem\endcsname
      {\def\makelabel##1{\hss\llap{##1}}%
       \addtolength{\itemsep}{-0.5em}}% <- Added changes...
  \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{itemize}
  \item First
  \item Second
  \item Third
  \item Last
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

A different approach would be to copy the definition of `\itemize` into a different macro (say `\tempitemize`) and then redefine `\itemize` to call `\tempitemize`, followed by your insertions:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item First
  \item Second
  \item Third
  \item Last
\end{itemize}

% Copy and redefine \itemize
\let\tempitemize\itemize % Store/copy \itemize in \tempitemize
\def\itemize{%
  \tempitemize % Original definition of \itemize
  \addtolength{\itemsep}{-0.5em}% <- Added changes...
}

\begin{itemize}
  \item First
  \item Second
  \item Third
  \item Last
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

The redefinition is a little simpler, but relies on the fact that your insertions happen *after* the (complete) execution of `\itemize`.

Maybe you don't want to fiddle with things at that level. The, perhaps, you can modify `\itemize` using a search-and-replace feature from [`etoolbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)'s `\patchcmd`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item First
  \item Second
  \item Third
  \item Last
\end{itemize}

% Patch \itemize to insert some code
% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\patchcmd{\itemize} % <cmd>
  {\fi} % <search>
  {\addtolength{\itemsep}{-0.5em}\fi} % <replace>
  {}{} % <success><failure>

\begin{itemize}
  \item First
  \item Second
  \item Third
  \item Last
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

The above patch would be similar to changing the original definition of `\itemize` to this:

```
\def\itemize{%
  \ifnum \@itemdepth >\thr@@\@toodeep\else
    \advance\@itemdepth\@ne
    \edef\@itemitem{labelitem\romannumeral\the\@itemdepth}%
    \expandafter
    \list
      \csname\@itemitem\endcsname
      {\def\makelabel##1{\hss\llap{##1}}}%
    \addtolength{\itemsep}{-0.5em}% <- Added changes...
  \fi}
```

While this is slightly different from the first and the second option, the result is the same. This solution relies on the fact that you know the structure of the command you're patching. That is, `\fi` has to be within `\itemize` in order for the patch to work, otherwise nothing happens. Moreover, the *first* occurrence of `\fi` is prepended with `\addtolength{\itemsep}{-0.5em}`, so you'll have issues if there are multiple `\fi`s within `\itemize` (say).

Finally, you can use an extendable approach with the [`enumitem` package](//ctan.org/pkg/enumitem):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item First
  \item Second
  \item Third
  \item Last
\end{itemize}

\setlist[itemize]{before = {\addtolength{\itemsep}{-0.5em}}}

\begin{itemize}
  \item First
  \item Second
  \item Third
  \item Last
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Of course, you could also specify a new value for `\itemsep` using the `itemsep = <value>` key-value approach

```
\setlist[itemize]{itemsep = <value>}
```

---

Note that inserting this before/after `equation` environments might be done in a better way by adjusting the values of

- `\abovedisplayskip` - length above a display equation that is preceded by a short line of text;
- `\abovedisplayshortskip` - length above a display equation that is preceded by a long line of text;
- `\belowdisplayskip` - similar to `\abovedisplayskip` but below the display equation; and
- `\belowdisplayshortskip` - similar to `\abovedisplayshortskip` but below the display equation.

For more on this, see

- [`\abovedisplayskip` vs `\abovedisplayshortskip`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30909/5764)
- [How to globally change the spacing around equations?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69662/5764)

Comment: Perfect! But and about equation environment? Should I open latex.ltx and redefine the piece of code in tex file or there is a package like enumitem?

Comment: @BismarckGomes -- it is *never* a good idea to change an established package directly, and even worse to change a core component such as `latex.ltx'.  if you want something you can use more than once, you can create your own little `.sty` file with the replacement code, and then call it with `\usepackage`.